# using pymongo load data to jupyter notebook and get collection list

Tags: pandas, pymongo

I am trying to connect mongo DB using pymongo.

how can I get collection list?

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import json
uri = "mongodb://XXX:abcd@dev-mongo.XXX.com/YYY?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
client = MongoClient(uri)


db = client['database_name']
collection=db['collection_name']
coll_list = db.collection_names()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pymongo

db_connect = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
database_name = 'MY_DATABASE_NAME'
database = db_connect[database_name]
collection = database.list_collection_names(include_system_collections=False)
for collect in collection:
    print (collect)
```